# Load jQuery/ajax in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax for my form because I don't want the page to reload after submit.
Now is everything working but the only problem is that the ajax script runs everytime I click the submit button.

I thought I could just paste the ajax in my if statement that tells when to run and when not, but it doesn't work.. anyone have any idea why?

```
theForm.onsubmit = function() {
if (pion == 1 || myName.value.length == 0 || myMessage.value.length == 0) {
    if (pion == 1 || emailValid.value.length == 0) {
        emailValid.style.border = "1px solid red";
        myError.innerHTML = "U heeft geen geldig e-mail adres ingevoerd.";
    }       
    if (myName.value.length == 0) {
        myName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        myError.innerHTML = "U heeft geen naam ingevuld.";
    }
    if (myMessage.value.length == 0) {
    myMessage.style.border = "1px solid red";
    myError.innerHTML = "U heeft geen bericht ingevuld.";
    }
    return false;
}

else {
    // the ajax I found somewhere, that works but not in this if/else statement
    $(function () {
        $('form').bind('submit', function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'mail.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
    });



    return true;

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code block:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'mail.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

bound the function that sends the AJAX request to your `form` element's `submit` event. Once it did, the function remains bound forever (or at least until you explicitly [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) it). That's why once your code falls in the `else` statement for the first time, the AJAX request will be sent every time the form is submit.

That said, your `if`/`else` logic should be inside the function that is bound to your `form's` submit event in order to send the AJAX request conditionally. Something like:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function () {
      if (etc etc etc) {
        // do other things
      }
      else {
        // send AJAX
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'mail.php',
          data: $('form').serialize(),
          success: function () {
            alert('form was submitted');
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> // the ajax I found somewhere

Copying/pasting code into your project without any knowledge of what that code does is a *famously* bad idea.

---

This code doesn't make an AJAX call:

```
$(function () {
    // anything in here
});
```

What this code does is tell jQuery to execute that function when the document is ready.  But presumably the document is *already* ready when you invoke this, since it's happening on a form submit event.

At best, depending on how the internals of jQuery works, it might be executing that inner function immediately.  But still, you don't need that wrapping call to jQuery.

But then, what is that function doing?:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function () {
  // anything in here
});
```

Again, it's not actually executing any AJAX code.  All this is doing is binding a function to the form's submit event.  That function may contain AJAX code (and in this case it does), but that's not being executed here.  It will be executed when the form is next submitted.

**But**, you're doing this *every time* you submit the form.  So what's happening is:

- User presses submit, nothing visibly happens.  1 event handler is bound to the next submit event.
- User presses submit, 1 event handler (AJAX) is executed, 2 event handlers are now bound to the next submit event.
- User presses submit, 2 event handlers (AJAX) are executed, 4 event handlers are now bound to the next submit event.
- and so on...

---

If you want to call the AJAX code in the `else` block, then just call it in the `else` block:

```
if (/* ... */) {
  // ...
} else {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'mail.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function () {
      alert('form was submitted');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: One more question.. If I put other lines of code in the else statement it doesn't work anymore.. any idea why? So i want to also add this line of code in 'else':
`myMessage.value = "";`

Comment: @user3124133: Define "it doesn't work".  Show the actual code you're using and describe the error.

Comment: `else {
  myMessage.value = "";
 
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'mail.php',
     data: $('form').serialize(),
     success: function () {
     }
   });
    return false;
    
}` That is the entire code in else

Comment: The ajax part is not working anymore because i don't get a mail after submit if I add the myMessage part.

Comment: @user3124133: "because i don't get a mail" isn't really a meaningful debugging process.  Use your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?  When you step through the code in the debugger, does it execute at all?  Is an AJAX request made to the server?  What is the server's response?  You need to debug your code, don't treat it as a black box.

Comment: The JavaScript console is empty.. other than that I don't know how to check on those things.. I was looking for something like that but didn't find it. But all I do is adding the line of code `myMessage.value = "";` or even any other simple line of code and the AJAX part doesn't work anymore.. Maybe because I mix javascript with jquery and ajax or something?

Comment: @user3124133: jQuery and AJAX *are* JavaScript.  You can safely "mix" JavaScript with JavaScript.  Assuming there isn't some other error somewhere else.  But, honestly, I can't debug your code on your machine for you.  You're *really* going to want to familiarize yourself with using a debugger.  Stack Overflow is a very, very poor replacement for a debugger.

Comment: @user3124133: Chrome developer tools and Firebug are probably the most widely used.  Any modern browser will have debugging tools.